# RecyclerView Adapter changes the values of the objects for no reason

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am listening to notifications and therefore I want to create a RecyclerView the user can use to exclude some apps. It shows the logo and the name of the app as well as a toggle button to enable/disable each app.

I created a class `App` containing some data of each app.

```
public class App {

    private String name;
    private String packageName;
    private Drawable icon;
    private boolean enabled;

    public App(String name, String packageName, Drawable icon, boolean enabled) {
        this.name = name;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

And this is the adapter:

```
public class AppsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsAdapter.AppViewHolder> {

    private List<App> apps;

    public AppsAdapter(PackageManager packageManager) {
        apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
                .stream()
                .filter(applicationInfo -> packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationInfo.packageName) != null)
                .map(applicationInfo -> new App(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(), applicationInfo.packageName, applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager), true))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public AppViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AppViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.app_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AppsAdapter.AppViewHolder holder, int position) {
        App app = apps.get(position);

        holder.nameTextView.setText(app.getName());
        holder.appToggleButton.setChecked(app.isEnabled());
        holder.iconImageView.setImageDrawable(app.getIcon());
    
        holder.appToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            app.setEnabled(isChecked);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return apps.size();
    }

    protected static class AppViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView nameTextView;
        private ToggleButton appToggleButton;
        private ImageView iconImageView;

        public AppViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
            appToggleButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_toggle_button);
            iconImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view);
        }
    }
}
```

When I "disable" an app by clicking the button, it seems to be working fine. But when I scroll down in the RecyclerView and then back up so the entry of the app I disabled is shown again on the screen, the app isn't disabled anymore.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to debug this and what might be causing this issue.

Edit:
If I call `setOnCheckedChangeListener` before `setChecked` on the toggle button, it seems to be working. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I see your setting checked change listener. When it is called you are calling app.setEnabled(isChecked) but you are not updating that app in the datasource.

Comment: The object is mutable. Therefore I do not need to re-add it to the data source.

Comment: When you set checked change listener in viewholder it works fine. I believe setting listeners in the viewholder is the proper way. otherwise it get set over and over in onBindView. something weird is happening though when the view gets recycled. Sorry I don't have a proper explanation, I'm trying to learn also.

Answer (score 0):

enabble setHasStableIds(true) in your adapter constructor.

```
AppsAdapter(){
setHasStableIds(true);
}
```